# How to combine 8 sql queries into one single result set?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have below 8 T-SQL scripts that I ran into a database and store that output into a spredsheet, how can we write a single query out of those 8 sql scripts so that I can ran it all once and store the results inside a table using SSIS? Is there any way to combine all the below SQL Scripts? We need to achive this in order to solve the manual process of running each of the queries one by one and storing the data inside the spreedsheet.

Comment: I am lazy to read through all the query. They look similar. What are the difference between each of the query ?

Comment: These queries are all extremely similar but appear to have been written by different people or at least at different times. They are all essentially doing nearly the same thing. What you really need to do is start from scratch and figure out what data you really want from the tables.

Answer (score 2):

`UNION ALL` comes to in mind :

```
SELECT MB.Member_Board_SName, ISNULL(A.[HeadCount],0) [HeadCount]
FROM . . 
UNION ALL
SELECT MB.Member_Board_SName, ISNULL(A.[HeadCount],0)
FROM . . . 
UNION ALL
. . .
```

Answer (score 0):

What everyone else said. You can also throw each individual result set into a temp table or something, if that provides you an advantage elsewhere in your script.

Answer (score -1):

In you case you need to make you column same in all queries, as the number of columns are 2 in your all query so you can use simply UNION ALL, it will return you all queries result as on output.

Specifically for you it will be:

```
WITH CertLevelParticipation AS
(
    SELECT
        MOC.ABMSUID,
        C.Member_Board_Id,
        MOC.Certificate_ID
    FROM 
        MOCParticipation MOC
    INNER JOIN 
        Certificate C ON MOC.Certificate_ID = C.Certificate_Id
    WHERE 
        MOC.Participating_Type = 'Y'
)
SELECT
    MB.Member_Board_SName,
    ISNULL(A.[HeadCount], 0) [HeadCount]..

UNION ALL 

SELECT
    MB.Member_Board_SName,
    ISNULL(A.[HeadCount], 0) [HeadCount]..

UNION ALL 

SELECT
    MB.Member_Board_SName,
    ISNULL(A.[HeadCount], 0) [HeadCount]..

UNION ALL 

SELECT
    MB.Member_Board_SName,
    ISNULL(A.[HeadCount], 0) [HeadCount]..

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
    MB.Member_Board_SName,  
    COUNT(DISTINCT ABMSUID) AS [HeadCount]..

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
    MB.Member_Board_SName,
    COUNT(DISTINCT ABMSUID) as [HeadCount]..

UNION ALL 

SELECT
    MB.Member_Board_SName,
    COALESCE(A.[HeadCount], B.[HeadCount], 0) AS [HeadCount]..

UNION ALL 

SELECT
    MB.Member_Board_SName,
    COALESCE(A.[HeadCount], B.[HeadCount], 0) AS [HeadCount]..
```

Comment: I am getting an error when using UNION ALL at the end of each statment

Comment: can you elaborate more as to where exactly I have to use Union ALL

Comment: This will never work. You can't just throw ctes in the middle like this.

Comment: yes @sean is correct. you need to make globally cte and then use inside

Comment: If you would at least make your answer syntactically valid it would go a long way to improving this. As it sits right now this is not a good answer because it won't work.

Comment: @user0001ttt i have added cte to top so now it should work for you. just you need add your rest code starting from From and Where clauses.

Comment: @SeanLange thanks, i never tested that code as it is not possible in this case. i just give an idea that how it will be done.